Is there a way to search by Middle Chinese rime?
Is there a website to search for all known Middle Chinese characters with a given final?  Or does everyone just thumb through huge JPEG scans of medieval documents?

https://ytenx.org/kyonh/yonh

@alephalpha, the site provided is unreliable, i explain it in the answer


Is there a website to search for all known Middle Chinese characters with a given final?

the “middle chinese”, i assumed you are talking about various versions of  切韻, or 廣韻
yes
the “japan society for the promotion of science” funded a research project, the result is hosted as the website: 宋本廣韻データ
briefly, there’re 5 pages:
廣韻上平聲卷第一
廣韻下平聲卷第二
廣韻上聲卷第三
廣韻去聲卷第四
廣韻入聲卷第五
have fun :)
about the site “韻典網”, as provided by @alephalpha
it is unreliable
for example: “鬱” u+9b31, it should be 紆物切 in 廣韻
but the site has 3 results, the first one is “於六切 郁小韻”; which is disinformation

the error is caused by, . . . the communist’s character simplification.
in traditional chinese, throughout history, “鬱” u+9b31 & “郁” u+90c1 are two distinguish characters.
only after 1950s, in “that area”, people collapsed these two into “郁”; that any database, website not according to traditional chinese would have such error.
further, the site “韻典網” is including “中原音韻”; omg, just avoid it 

Thanks!  My Korean is good enough but my Japanese is too terrible to have found this.  I really appreciate it.

@RobertMarshallMurphy, actually, when i still had a macos machine, i downloaded these five pages, using terminal.app search “locally” by shell command grep  in case of double check, i used the 5 pdf files of 鉅宋廣韻 https://www.digital.archives.go.jp/DAS/meta/result?IS_KIND=hierarchy&IS_NUMBER=100&IS_START=1&IS_TAG_S51=prnid&IS_STYLE=default&IS_KEY_S51=F1000000000000094954&IS_EXTSCH=F2009121017025600406%2BF2005031812174403109%2BF2008112110364221711%2BF1000000000000094954&IS_ORG_ID=F1000000000000094954&LIST_TYPE=default&IS_SORT_FLD=sort.tror%2Csort.refc&IS_SORT_KND=asc

I cannot comment on the reliability of the site, but the particular evidence/argument doesn't support the conclusion. 郁 only showed up because the "簡化字" function is turned on (by default, presumably to facilitate the usage by users of simplified characters). If you disable the conversion function it does not show up.

In 高級檢索, if you check only 廣韻 and de-select everything else (including 異體字轉換), you'd only get the second search result.

@joehua, here’s a metaphor: supposed one ordered a pizza in a restaurant, in you-guess-where; somehow, one need to perform “advance table manner”, for picking out the sands & pebbles before eating  isn’t it absurd? what is normal should be: when the waiter delivered the pizza, one can eat it immediately

@xngtng, above comment is a metaphor of pizza, have a read; please

@水巷孑蠻 Your metaphor seems absurd. It may not be a user-friendly site (for you; many Mainland users may prefer that way using their normal input methods: it is not a hard task to distinguish the different traditional forms for educated people who are interested in the history), but it does not support your conclusion about reliability. And the implication that the database they use does not distinguish traditional characters is just false (and technically absurd: of course they are using Unicode and not based on simplified/traditional system, otherwise you wouldn't even see the results.).

As another alternative to the websites above, I suggest zi.tools too. It also supports other rime tables, along with dialectical and old chinese reconstructions (Click on phonology at the top for this). However, I can't find any sources on how accurate it is, so don't take my word on it, but it has served me really well, having  a lot of information other sites just don't have.
